# Does Android layout-large also mean larger than large?

Tags: android, layout

Simple and short question but it seems that I can't find the answer anywhere. When creating a layout-large folder will a device with a xlarge screen also use this folder?

So does layout-large also mean larger than large? I assume it will, but not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No , when you have created folder layout-large it will not use by xlarge screen but if you want to use xml for xlarge layout you can use `layout-xlarge`.If there is no  `layout-xlarge` then android system use default layout in that case.

Comment: This will increase my application size because i use the same layout for large and xlarge, but that's how it is. It seems that not everyone is capable of reading a question as it should be, 1 out of 3 answers is actually answering my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For xlarge devices use

Layout-xlarge.device will automatically load it

check this link

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html.  it will give u a brief idea

Comment: What if i want to use the same layout on both large and xlarge? Do i have to copy all my files? This seems a bit useless and makes my application unnecessary larger. So does large mean:  "large and up?"

Comment: if u provided layout for xlarge(layout-xlarge)it automatically use it and u will get proper layout for u r device.if u r not used then u can not assure multiple device screen compatibilty.Go through that link and create emultor for 7.1 Tab and 10.1 Tab u will see the diffrence

Comment: "if u r not used then u can not assure multiple device screen compatibilty". That depends on the layout your using. But in fact your right.

Answer (score 0):

There is layout-xlarge for extra large screen. You can refer [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for more details about supporting multiple screens